# How to only allow an admin to shut down a program?

Tags: c#, forms, windows-services, admin, uac

I am working on my year 3 Project at Uni.

An integral part of the feature is that only an admin can mess with the program this includes:

- Install
- Uninstall
- Settings (Files)

and Finally, the controversial; 'Shutting down the program'.

Here is what I currently have in mind.

Windows Form App, Launches at startup, takes note of all kinds of things, and monitors and prevents others, shuts down with the PC (not sure how to make the program exit nicely on shutdown? )and then should the computer be turned on again the program is there at startup, doing its job.

I am not sure if its better for a windows service, but the program definitely needs a windows form interface so users can login (should an admin require to do so, through a user account).

Could anyone counsel me on whether a windows service would be better, if so, some good documentation on them? I looked and tried out the MSDN tutorial but without much luck or even understanding.

I know it's bad practice to interfere with the user, and prevent them from closing a program, but its all part of a functionality that an admin would knowingly install.

O yea, I forgot to mention the program would be installed.

Comment: Consider having your program run as a service.  If you've ever used an antivirus program, that's how most of them operate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

normally this is done with user permissioning and roles.. you create users and assign them roles. if a given user who is trying to "close" is having "admin" role then we allow him otherwise we dont. you can put these users in registry and create a windows service that your program can talk to or directly query.

Comment: Would I make the Windows Service and then ask it to integrate the program? Or would I make the program and then look about integrating a windows service. It's going to be big, so how best do I approach it? 

Should I just make the program and then redo the bits?